# What is this 'timber insert' on the construction drawing of a concrete parapet wall?

Tags: civil-engineering, drawings

A sectional elevation of a concrete roof is shown below (drawing is from the early 70s):

[image]

The roof slab is dimensioned as 6" thick with what appears to be 12" parapet wall with a 'Timber Insert'.

What is the purpose of this timber insert? Is it for fixing into?

My assumption is that it does not protrude beyond the face of the concrete i.e. it is not a sheet of timer forming a secondary roof.

Comment: What climate is this building in?  It could be an architectural feature trying to show a grove on the inside face.  It also appears to be on two sides if not three.  Its not shown in the wall to the right.  I could be for a timbre roof since there is nothing shown for ballast on top of the insulation.  If it were a reglet I would assume something more like the small square on the right beside the leader arrow.  pure guess work here so only commenting.